# wifi is v poor - ubuntu 23.10 - realtek

Tags: wireless, 23.10

My wifi is very poor and erratic on upgrade to 23.10.  Also I note that I get very poor speeds when i connect to ethernet.
My laptop has the realtek wifi adapter.  It used to cause problems - the wifi adapter was not identified by ubuntu, but that has not been a problem for a while. I wonder if it could be an issue with the realtek chip.  I think that the adapter is rtl8821ce.
I'd be grateful for any advice.  Thank you

Here is the output of

```
lspci -nnk -d ::0280

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
DeviceName: Realtek RTL8188EE 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
Kernel driver in use: rtw_8821ce
Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce
```

Comment: Append output of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk -d ::0280`

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
 DeviceName: Realtek RTL8188EE 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
 Kernel driver in use: rtw_8821ce
 Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce
c@c-Type1ProductConfigId:~$

Comment: Please edit your main post to add command output

Comment: I fixed it by disabling secure boot.  Fast and reliable wifi again.  Thanks!

Comment: You can self-answer then

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by disabling secure boot. Fast and reliable wifi again.
Thanks RA for help